# Is it possible to retrieve AUTH_SESSION_ID cookie from Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I am working with java ee application where we authenticate via keycloak and during redirect we see AUTH_SESSION_ID in the cookie but after the log out its not there which might be creating problems (multiple redirect issue). SO we want to retrieve that and expire the cookie in the log out page.

update:
keycloak version is 3.4.3
we are using it to secure a java ee application running on wildfly 10
we use keycloak-wildfly adapter.
The multiple-redirect happens after the user is taken to application page after authentication.

Comment: so for me is not clear what your problem is. What I understand from this is that you have the KEYCLOAK_SESSION in the cookies and then you want to save it, because when you do a logout it is deleted, but then you want it just to make sure it is deleted after the logout. Which makes no sense.

Comment: Sometimes in a weird scenario this AUTH_SESSION_ID cookie persists even when I log out and then when I try to login back then it keeps on redirecting and finally fails due to multiple redirects. So I want to make sure that when I log out I expire any such cookie.

Comment: Please, describe the concrete problem better. When does the redirect happen? Which KC version? Do you use any KC adapter to securize your application?

Comment: updated the problem

Comment: I would try to install a cookie manager in my browser and after the logout delete all the cookies for the app domain and the keycloak domain and then do a login to be sure that this is the problem. If this the problem persist try to debug it and check all your network trafic in the browser. When you have more info about the multi-redirects let us know what exactly your problem/question is.

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem was with the code itself where it was creating multiple sessions even when a valid session already existed and those multiple encrypted session keys were being kept as cookies with same name which was were causing multiple re-direct issues. anyways, I appreciate all of your help. And regarding AUTH_SESSION_ID I figured it out that we can get it from JWT, the claim is session_state.